# Disable deleting of SharedPreferences via Android Application Manager

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Is there a way to disable deleting of sharedPreferences when user delete application data via android application manager?

I am building application with users. I want to enable only one user per mobile phone, so in first screen i let users login / register and after that i put their information in sharedpreferences. When they start application after login/registration, app check for sharedpreferences about users and if they exists it start second screen of app.

So is it possible to disable their deleting, and if not how can i get some kind of unique device number or something, that i can store in my online database, and check if one user is allrdy registered via that mobile device when he tries to log in with another user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way to Disable deleting of SharedPreferences.

But you can use strong logic to get your requirement.

Store **device IMEI no.** on **server** for registered users.

You can **check IMEI no.** with server and **accordingly show register or login interface.**

**Make sure while login you send IMEI no. to check user registered with device is only logging in.**

Comment: And how can i get device imei number?

Comment: TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)c.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String imei = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();

c is Context

You will need

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

Comment: what about tablet without TELEPHONY_SERVICE?

Comment: You can use registration id generated by GCM.Its unique for each device [link](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html)
Getting reg id from gcm is very easy just call register() method of GCM

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to disable deleting of sharedPreferences when user delete application data via android application manager?

No. They can also get rid of `SharedPreferences` via the "Clear Data" button for their app in Settings. Rooted device users can also just delete the file.